# How to filter the contents of a single row of CSV in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a rather dumb question :)

I have a CSV, such as this:

```
"test","bla","monkey","test3"
1,2,3,4
4,3,2,1
```

I am importing into a variable, such as $data
How can I filter just the first row - for example, I only want to pull back row entries with "test* in the name?

Thank you!

Comment: If you only want to get the first row, you could use $data | Select-Object -First 1

Comment: Csv file has no header row?

Answer (score 2):

Posting an answer based on some assumptions even though you have no existing code that needs to be massaged.

Assuming you have no heard row, assigning an arbitrary number to the column count and loading into a variable called `$csv`

```
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Temp\test.csv -Header @(1..4)
```

Now using the `$csv` variable and making a query to return the results into the $data variable you speak of where they match "test in the first column"

```
$data = $csv | ? { $_.1 -match "test"}
```

The result stored in `$data` should now be as follows.

```
1    2   3      4
-    -   -      -
test bla monkey test3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using PowerShell v3, and have nothing to go on, so I'll just list the easiest way to grab the first row.

```
$csv = Import-Csv c:\test\test.csv
$csv[0]
```

This will return the first item in the $csv object, Import-Csv will recognize row 1 as the header by default, will need to use the -Header flag if a header row isn't present.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for input.  I realize my explanation of what I wanted was over simplified and too vague.  I actually wanted to get the names of the header row so that I could filter by headers containing a specific word. So this is what worked:

```
$csv = Import-Csv c:\temp\test.csv
$filteredResults = ($csv | get-member | ?{$_.Name -like "*test*"}).Name
```

which returns to the variable:

```
test
test3
```